# When I do npm start after build in nextjs, I get an error. (Could not find a production build in the "example/out" directory

Tags: reactjs, next.js, build, static, next.js13

I got error after npm run build. (local build)

error message is this.

```
Could not find a production build in the '/Documents/nextjs_projects/project_name/out' directory. Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the production server. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/production-start-no-build-id
```

Most of the answers I've found are to build before start, which I've already tried.

I've tried these things

1. npx next build // npx next start
2. npm run build // npm run start
3. in npm build command, use "next build && next export"
   -> I used output: 'export' in next.config.js because I'm using the next.js 13.3 version.

my next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
  distDir: "out",
  images: {
    domains: ["cdn.mywebsite.com", "localhost"],
  },
  output: 'export'
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

after build, I have static files in "out" directory.

How can I fix this problem? :(

help me plz.